# Are simplicial abelian sheaves fibrant?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-presheaves

I want to show that simplicial abelian sheaves are fibrant. For this, I wonder whether a morphism between simplicial sheaves is a fibration iff it has RLP w.r.t. all morphisms like
$$\Lambda^n_k\times X\to\triangle^n\times X$$
where $X\in Sm/k$. Is this claim true?

Here weak equivalences are stalkwise weak equivalences and cofibrations are monomorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fibrant in what model structure?

Simplicial abelian sheaves (and presheaves) are fibrant
in the projective model structure because
all simplicial abelian groups are fibrant.

Simplicial abelian sheaves are definitely
not fibrant in the local projective model structure
because sheaf cohomology groups can be nontrivial.
For a specific example, consider the simplicial abelian sheaf
Γ(Z[1]) on the site of smooth manifolds,
given by applying the Dold-Kan functor Γ
to the chain complex of sheaves Z[1] given by placing
the constant sheaf Z in chain degree 1.
If the simplicial abelian sheaf Γ(Z[1]) was fibrant in the local projective model structure,
than the sheaf cohomology of a smooth manifold M
in degree 1 with coefficients in Z
could be computed by evaluating Γ(Z[1]) on M
and then taking the homology group in degree 0.
However, the homology group of Γ(Z[1])(M) in degree 0 is 0 for any M,
a contradiction with the case M=S^1, for which H^1(S^1,Z)=Z.

Comment: I definitely agree with the first line. but I don't quite see the relation between being fibrant in the local projective model structure and having trivial sheaf cohomology.

Comment: @SimonHenry: I added a specific example.

Comment: I mean the injective model structure. That is why I want to find a system of generators.

Comment: @NanjunYang: The generators you wrote down are precisely the generating cofibrations for the projective and local projective model structures.  The prevailing opinion with respect to the generating cofibrations for the injective model structure is that there is no explicit such a set of generators, excluding some special categories of presheaves (but Sm/k is not one of them).

Comment: So are the simplicial abelian sheaves still fibrant under injective model structure? I want to prove that the Eilenberg MacLane spectra are stably fibrant finally, thus I have to show that $K(A,n)$ is injectively fibrant. I've been using injective model structures.

Comment: Maybe $K(A,n)$ isn't injectively fibrant in general. I think I could avoid this statement.

Comment: @NanjunYang: In the motivic context, you would need K(A,n)=Γ(A[n]) to be locally injectively fibrant and not just injectively fibrant.  The argument in my post shows that K(A,n)=Γ(A[n]) is not a local object, so cannot be locally injectively fibrant.  Even ignoring locality, though, I am pretty sure that K(A,n)=Γ(A[n]) is not injectively fibrant.  Why not use the projective local model structure instead, where the Eilenberg–MacLane spectra seem to be fibrant?

Comment: My final decision is to use the Brown-Gersten model structure. I think $K(A,n)$ is fibrant if $A$ is injective.

Comment: @NanjunYang: The Brown–Gersten model structure is the projective model structure on simplicial sheaves.  Everything I said about the projective and local projective model structures applies also to the Brown–Gersten model structure.